# Setting up a remote Mercurial repository

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I have a mercurial repo set up on a server and I'd like to be able to access it remotely. How would I go by doing that?

Answer (score 3):

for "me" as the owner: ssh

for the public: http (via 'hg serve')

Answer (score 3):

The [mercurial book section on collaboration](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html) has some setup help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [Publishing Repositories?](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories)